# How to handle complex dependency in maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have project A with module B, C.

in **A pom.xml** i have  defined properties like.

```
  <properties>
    <test.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</smp.version>
   </properties>
   <modules>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
   <modules>
```

**moduleB's** pom.xml is like below,

```
  <modules>
    <module>X</module>
  </modules>
```

**module X's** which have dependency for **Proj1** (some external jar)w ith vesrion defined in parent pom test.version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>group1</groupId>
        <artifactId>Proj1</artifactId>
        <version>${test.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now **module C** depend on **module B** , as module C can be deployed individually also, all the dependencis that are required for B needs to be included to C.

Now the problem is while building **project A** i.e. parent project I pass -Dtest.version=1.0.0

so module B is build with proj1's  **1.0.0** version

But module C (as it depends on B ) it is created with Proj1's **1.0.0-SNAPSHOT** version. while building project C, it takes the default value of test.version, which i don't want. both B, C should refer to same version of proj1.

EDIT: module C 's pom

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>B's group id </groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>${B's.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

So i have

Parent A

|

A's child module B -> B's child module X -> external proj1 jar with test version

A's child module C -> dependency to module B

I know it is very complex. but i am not sure if this can be simplified too.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now module C depend on module B , as module C can be deployed individually also, all the dependencis that are required for B needs to be included to C." Single modules are usually not deployed individually. Their dependencies are usually resolved automatically.

Comment: What does the POM of module C look like?

Comment: I mean to say is, some other project can add module C as a dependency and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your question, but the `<dependencyManagement>` can help you to define a cross dependency version, as long as you place it in the parent-pom (project A) file.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group1</groupId>
        <artifactId>Proj1</artifactId>
        <version>${test.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: so <dependencyManagement> will made sure that dependency of proj1 is available to all child modules of A. Right?

Comment: No, it will just set the default `version` for it so you won't need to set it over and over. If you want all the sub-modules to include this dependency, just placed it in the this dependency in the `<dependencies>` section on project A's `pom.xml`

Comment: ok... in case dependencyManagement , i will write below in A's pom and whata  about  B and C's pom. Do i need add anything about proj1 there?                                                                          <dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group1</groupId>
        <artifactId>Proj1</artifactId>
        <version>${test.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement

Comment: Don't write version into the child POMs if you specify it in parent's dependencyManagement.

Answer (score 1):

It is not complex. Just keep in mind- dependency hierarchy manages through perent- child, not through modules.
That means modules B, C in project A may have different parents with different dependencies and dependencyManagement definitions.
 Modules tag defines only what to build in project A, but not to how to build or what dependency to use.